# Can I populate multiple fields in my Podio app using Email to App?

Tags: format, email, podio

I've been trying to populate a Podio app using Email to App.

However, the problem is that the app only takes 3 blocks of data from an email submission: the subject, the sender, and the body. This would be sufficient if I had two fields of data to populate. However, I have 10 fields of data to populate in the app.

How can I send an email with the 10 fields of data and populate an app entry?

[This article from 2010](https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201019648-Email-to-app) is the only thing Podio says about this feature and yet it is not working for me. I have tried sending an email with

```
name:my name
location: my location
car: my car
...
```

in the body, and the Podio app simply places the entirety of the email in each field.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot populate multiple fields with Email to App feature in Podio. To handle. Use [Podio API](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/add-new-item-22362) for advanced use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Populating multiple fields to Podio still works as descibed in https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201019648-Email-to-app.

**Email to item configuration**:
[image]

---

**Example email text**:
[image]

---

**Resulted item created**:
[image]

Comment: Hi what about the link field? Link is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to populate the data. 
You could put the 10 items into the email body and send them as formatted text into Podio.

If you have dynamic data, you could achieve this by e.g. iterating through an array.

Other than that you have to use the API.

Comment: "send as formatted text..."? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The method in the post you link to is correct and works.

In the email the format:

fieldname: content

.. gets mapped with "content" being put into the item's field with the name "fieldname". Use the field mapping user interface if you want to choose which fieldname:-label from the email maps to which field in the Podio item.